# Paste two files in bash (columns side by side)

Tags: bash, paste

I'm having some problem with paste command in bash

I have a bunch of three comma separated column text files that share columns 2 and 3. First I create a txt file by extracting this shared columns from a single data file

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," }{ print $2 "," $3}' file01.txt > msg-coord.txt
```

Then I run through a loop to get the first column of each file in the list

```
for hora
in 00 01 02 03
do

awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," }{ print $1 }' file$hora.txt > a$hora.txt

done
```

then try to paste all new files (runs fine)

```
paste -d "," a{00..03}.txt > temporal.txt
```

and add the msg-coord.txt through paste command, this is not working and I can't find out why

```
paste -d "," msg-coord.txt temporal.txt > msgdata.txt
```

Output of `head msgdata.txt` yields

```
,-0.0127,-0.1773,-0.3749,-0.3780 
,-0.0318,-0.1941,-0.3780,-0.3877
,-0.0510,-0.2109,-0.3807,-0.3973
,-0.0703,-0.2277,-0.3833,-0.4068
,-0.0900,-0.2450,-0.3864,-0.4168
,-0.1101,-0.2632,-0.3903,-0.4272
```

where the two columns from msg-coord.txt are missing.

fileXX.txt look like

```
 -0.3686,-12.5000,33.5000
 -0.3877,-12.5000,33.5800
 -0.3973,-12.5000,33.6200
 -0.4068,-12.5000,33.6600
 -0.4168,-12.5000,33.7000
 -0.4272,-12.5000,33.7400
 -0.4382,-12.5000,33.7800
 -0.4504,-12.5000,33.8200
 -0.4638,-12.5000,33.8600
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I suspect msg-coord.txt has DOS line endings; the carriage return at the end of each line causes the contents following it in `msgdata.txt` to overwrite the first part of each line. (This assumes that the `file*.txt` files have exactly 3 columns and have DOS line endings, so that the carriage return is carried over with column 3.)

Comment: @chepner You were right , this data files come from a Windows system. Adding a `dos2unix` command was the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the DOS line endings from the data files (`file*.txt`?) before combining them.